# Substitue for the Tilde in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, substitution, tilde

I'm trying to execute a script in MATLAB that uses a tilde. 
However, earlier versions of MATLAB doesn't support the tilde. 
How can I substitute for the tilde?

Here is the code:

```
                fname = 'worldmap.png';
                img = imread(fname);
                [imgH,imgW,~] = size(img);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a dummy variable in place of the tilde when it is not supported in your version

```
 [imgH, imgW, dummy_variable] = size(img);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I forgot about the dummy variable.

Answer (score 2):

The de-facto dump variable in older versions of matlab is 'ans', as it gets overwritten all the time anyway.